# Access to undefined member variables when exposing a class in boost python

Tags: boost-python

I'm struggling with some unwanted side effects of exposing a class in boost.python. It seems that in Python, it is legal to assign to a member variable that was never defined in the original class. So in the example below I define a class with a member 'a', but also writing to a member 'b' works in Python. This has the (in my case negative) side effect that I can't detect typos when accessing class members, since myClass.complicatedObjectName=1 works and myclass.complicatedObjectname=1 works as well, even if the latter variable is never defined. As illustration, when exposing a class like this

```
#include <boost/python.hpp>
using namespace boost::python;

class A {
public:
  A() : a(1) {}
  int a;
};

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(liba)  {
  class_<A>("A", init<>())
  .def_readonly("a", &A::a);
}
```

and trying to acces A.a and A.b

```
import liba
myA = liba.A()
print "a", myA.a
myA.b = 1
print "b", myA.b
```

generates the output:

```
a 1
b 1
```

I would prefer the assignment 'myA.B = 1' to fail. Is there a way to make boost.python behave like this?

I'm sorry if this question is already asked somewhere, but I couldn't find an answer. Thanks for pointing me to existing answers if there is one.

I'm working with the standard boost libraries (v 1.54) on Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In python you can override `_setattr_` to only allow attribute names from a defined list. Here is how to do that: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3079306/how-to-protect-againt-typos-when-setting-value-for-class-members](http://how-to-protect-againt-typos-when-setting-value-for-class-members).

Then some ideas how to achieve the same in C++: [How to override __setattr__ in a wrapped class (from C++)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10694367/how-to-override-setattr-in-a-wrapped-class-from-c) and [Catch creation of instance attributes of boost::python-wrapped classes from c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6120490/catch-creation-of-instance-attributes-of-boostpython-wrapped-classes-from-c).

Comment: Oh, I see, it's a Python feature/problem/difference-to-C. Thanks for the links, I'll try these approaches for my most important cases.